# Using @lazy properties in functions causes build errors

Tags: swift

I am trying to limit a classes scope to within a function. This seems to work:

```
func foo() {
    class MyClass {
        var s = ""
    }
}
```

I can create instances of MyClass within the foo() function.

However, when I attempt to add the @lazy specifier to a property...

```
func foo() {
    class MyClass {
        @lazy var s = ""
    }
}
```

... I get the following build errors:

> - Global is external, but doesn't have external or weak linkage!
> - invalid linkage type for function declaration
> - LLVM ERROR: Broken module found, compilation aborted!

---

Note: If I move the class out of the function's scope, the code compiles:

```
class MyClass {
    @lazy var s = ""
}
```

Why is this failing, and how should this error be resolved? If it cannot be resolved, is there another way to use @lazy properties inside of functions?

Comment: Did you report this? https://bugreport.apple.com/

Comment: I've also had some issues with lazy vars causing compiler crashes; in my case it was related to protocol conformance. Need to file that radar. :|

Answer (score 0):

The following code works for me:

```
func foo() -> String {
    class bar {
        lazy var baz = "qux"
    }
    return bar().baz
}

foo() // prints "qux"
```

Looks like there was a bug in the early Swift laguage version, which has been reolved.

Answer (score 0):

I can confirm akashivskyy's observation. I've tried it as well and the this code works for me as well:

```
func foo() {
    class MyClass {
        var variable = "string"
    }
    let instance = MyClass()
    println(instance.variable)
}

foo() // "string" is printed
```

It's not the first time for me that I've actually encountered some issues in earlier Swift versions. I mean it's still a pretty young language and thus it needs always some improvements and bug fixes.

Are you using the newest version of Swift and Xcode?